# How to annotate "typeof" inheritor of certain class (not it's instance) in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Assume that

```js
abstract class Controller {}

class ProductController extends Controller {}
class CommentController extends Controller {}
```

Currently the type annotation of parameter of `testFunction` means "class Controller itself, not it's instance":

```js
function testFunction(ControllerClass: typeof Controller): void {
   const instance: Controller = new ControllerClass();
}
```

The function is invalid, because we can not create the instances of abstract class.

Now how to specify "type of any inheritor of `Controller`"? I don't mean the instances, I mean the classes like `ProductController` or `CommentController`.

```js
function testFunction(SpecificControllerClass: typeof /*???*/): void {
   const controllerInstance: /*???*/ = new SpecificControllerClass();
}
```

I don't know how generics could be used in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of the parameter as a **constructor** instead of a **class**:

```js
function testFunction(ControllerClass: new () => Controller): void {
  const instance: Controller = new ControllerClass();
}
```

```js
testFunction(Controller) // Error: Cannot assign an abstract constructor type to a non-abstract constructor type.

testFunction(ProductController) // Passes
```